# Complicated oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle

I've got a really complicated query that I need do but I just can't seem to get my head around how to accomplish it so I'm hoping someone can help me.

I have two queries which I need to make into one query.

My first query is this:

```
select * from table1 t1 
join table2 t2 on t2.outcode = t1.post_code
```

This produces results which include `LAT` and `LONG` of the postcode like so:

```
  Name    Postcode          Lat         Long
Taylor         CB8    53.829517    -1.780320
```

These are just dummy values for test purposes.

My next query is this

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT t3.location_name, 
    calc_distance(t3.lat, t3.lng, t2.lat,t2.lng) as distance
    FROM table3 t3, table2 t2 
    where t2.outcode = :postcode
    order by distance) i 
where rownum = 1
```

`calc_distance` is a function that calculates the distance based on LAT & LONG of a point

If I substitute `:postcode` with `CB8` it produces these results

```
Location_name     Distance
  NR Location         56.6
```

What I somehow need to do is produce the following output from a single query.

```
  Name    Postcode          Lat         Long    Nearest_Loc     Distance
Taylor         CB8    53.829517    -1.780320    NR Location         56.6
```

I can't for the life of me work out how to produce this if it is possible.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Try left join with first query.

Comment: @Vishal can you expand on that? I have tried a left join but can't see what to left join on?

Comment: As an aside, you might find that [Oracle Locator](http://docs.oracle.com/html/B10826_01/sdo_locator.htm) is better suited for this kind of thing that your user-defined function. If nothing else, the SDO_GEOMETRY type can be indexed, which can make queries of this sort considerably faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` effectively here. By Partioning on `t2.outcode` and sorting by `distance` we can find the smallest distance for each outcode (`t3.rn = 1`).

```
SELECT 
       t1.Name,
       t1.Postcode,
       t2.Lat,         
       t2.Long,    
       t3.Nearest_Loc,
       t3.Distance
From 
      table1 t1 
       INNER join table2 t2 on t2.outcode = t1.post_code
    LEFT JOIN (
               SELECT t3.location_name, 
                     calc_distance(t3.lat, t3.lng, t2.lat,t2.lng) as distance,
                     row_number() over (partition by t2.outcode 
                                        order by calc_distance(t3.lat, t3.lng, t2.lat,t2.lng) 
                                      ) rn,
                    t2.outcode
               FROM table3 t3, table2 t2 
            ) t3
     on t1.Postcode =  t3.PostCode
      and t3.rn = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I seemed to be getting a `ORA-06553 - wrong number or types arguments` error and it seems to be to do with this line `row_number() over (partition by t2.outcode order by distance) rn,` any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can use the distance alias in the row_number() try this `row_number() over (partition by t2.outcode order by calc_distance(t3.lat, t3.lng, t2.lat,t2.lng)) `

Comment: Brilliant - Thank you so much its been doing my head in for days now!

Comment: Can you please share you calc_distance function ..?